# Cordova sound not playing on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2017, android-7.0-nougat

I am making an app using the Cordova framework. As development environment I am using Visual Studio 2017. VS allows me to access emulators for debugging.

My app has a sound that I want to play every time the user clicks on a button. This works perfectly when using an emulator to debug - the sound plays everytime, no problem.
But when I deploy the app to my device (which is running Android 7.0) the sound never plays. (I made sure that my phone wasn't muted.)

I was thinking maybe there is some android-specific error in my code. Here's my code:

```
function playAudio() {  //is called everytime the user clicks a button
    var media = new Media("www/sounds/roll.wav");
    media.play();
}
```

Comment: Permission issue? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova/media/media.html#permissions

Comment: @RonNabuurs I tried: adding a namespace for Android, and then adding the permissions, but it didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't the location be `/android_asset/www/sounds/roll.wav`?

Comment: @RonNabuurs There is no android_asset folder in the root directory (by default). There is a res folder, however. I tried adding a raw folder to it, and placing the roll.wav file in it ( /res/raw/roll.wav ), but it didn't work. Should I create the android_asset folder in the root?